# How to change microphone volume/gain settings in LineageOS?

Tags: lineageos

I'm using LineageOS (it says it is Android 10).

First time I'm trying to use headphone mic, and I got very surprised (and very, very pissed) that there isn't anything in Settings where I can regulate which mic do I want to be active, and the gain/volume for the microphone.

So is it possible to change microphone settings in LineageOS - and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I also had a microphone volume problem in recording apps (not on phone calls).

It's probably very device and OS specific, but I was able to change it by editing `/system/vendor/etc/mixer_paths_0.xml`. It requires root to `mount /system -o remount,rw` and to write the file.

In the following section I changed the `MIC3 Volume` value from `4` to `25` :

```
        <path name="gain-media-headset-mic">
                <ctl name="MIC3 Volume" value="4" />
                <ctl name="MIC3 Boost Volume" value="2" />
                <ctl name="ADC Left Gain" value="127" />
                <ctl name="ADC Right Gain" value="127" />
        </path>
```

The phone is on LineageOS 16 (Android 9).